# Can not move back and forth the video in Chrome Browser using VideoJs

Tags: angular, google-chrome, video.js

When clicking play button and move the video forward, it plays again from start. I experience this issue in Chrome Browser while in FireFox Browser it works fine.

Library: VideoJS v7, videojs-seek-buttons v3
Framework: Angular v14

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the server hosting the video does not repsond correctly to range headers, sending the start of the file instead of the part requested.